# Azure Role Assignment - AKS to ACR - Terraform

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, terraform, acr, azure-aks

I am using the Terraform code below, to create a resource group, create an AKS cluster and i am trying to allow the AKS cluster to use an existing ACR in the same subscription, using the data {} reference. It works fine without the role assignment block, but when i use that i keep getting the below error

```
Error: Invalid index

  on main.tf line 40, in resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "aks_to_acr_role":
  40:   principal_id         = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks.kubelet_identity[0].object_id
    |----------------
    | azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks.kubelet_identity is empty list of object

The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.
```

I have looked all over stack exchange, microsoft azure docs and Terraform issues and lots of blog posts, i honestly have no idea what is wrong at this point. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
      name     = var.resource_group_name
      location = var.location
    }

    resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "aks" {
      name                = var.cluster_name
      kubernetes_version  = var.kubernetes_version
      location            = var.location
      resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
      dns_prefix          = var.cluster_name

      default_node_pool {
        name                = "system"
        node_count          = var.system_node_count
        vm_size             = "Standard_B2ms"
        type                = "VirtualMachineScaleSets"
        availability_zones  = [1, 2, 3]
        enable_auto_scaling = false
      }

      service_principal {
        client_id     = var.appId
        client_secret = var.password
      }

    }
    data "azurerm_container_registry" "acr_name" {
      name = "xxxxx"
      resource_group_name = "xxxxx"
    }
    resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "aks_to_acr_role" {
      scope                = data.azurerm_container_registry.acr_name.id
      role_definition_name = "AcrPull"
      principal_id         = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks.kubelet_identity[0].object_id
      skip_service_principal_aad_check = true
    }
```

ACR name and RG name are xxxxx out of the code just for privacy

Comment: as it is marked in the error, azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks.kubelet_identity returns an empty list of object. The reason is that you don't define kubelet_identity block inside azurerm_kubernetes_cluster

Comment: define kubelet_identity block inside azurerm_kubernetes_cluster

Comment: If i use an identity block, Terraform complains about the use of service principal and identity block together @MoonHorse

Comment: apologies you mean this - kubelet_identity {} I will try that now and see if it works, thanks for your help

Comment: @MoonHorse - thanks but that hasn't worked. Error still persists. I will keep searching

Comment: Hello @BrianRyan, Kublet_identity can't be configured with service principal , as service principal is being used as identity , so it will empty. You can provide the service Principal object Id in the role assignment block. and if you want to use kublet identity then you can't use service principal , you have to use identity `system assisgned or user-assigned`

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to check in here today, i was busy with other tasks. Thank you so much for the help and guidance, I changed the Terraform script last night and used managed identity instead of service principal and it worked fine. So as you say, i used system assigned. Thanks for all the great help to everyone who commented and took the time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While Using the `Service Principal` as a identity for Kubernetes cluster the `kubelet_identity` will be **empty** as you have not defined `identity` block while creating the AKS Cluster . The `Identity block` conflicts with `Service Principal Block` so, they can't be used together .

**Solutions:**

1. You can use **Identity as SystemAssigned instead of Service
   Principal** then you don't have to configure the `kubelet_identity`
   block ,it will automatically get preconfigured and you can use
   `azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks.kubelet_identity[0].object_id`
   successfully. So, your code will be like below:

   ```
   provider"azurerm"{
       features{}
   }
   data "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
         name     = "ansumantest"
   }

       resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "aks" {
         name                = "ansumantestaks"
         location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
         resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
         dns_prefix          = "ansumantestaks-dns"

         default_node_pool {
           name                = "system"
           node_count          = 1
           vm_size             = "Standard_B2ms"
           type                = "VirtualMachineScaleSets"
           availability_zones  = [1, 2, 3]
           enable_auto_scaling = false
         }
          identity{
              type = "SystemAssigned"
          }
       }
       data "azurerm_container_registry" "acr_name" {
         name = "ansumantestacr"
         resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
       }
       resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "aks_to_acr_role" {
         scope                = data.azurerm_container_registry.acr_name.id
         role_definition_name = "AcrPull"
         principal_id         = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks.kubelet_identity[0].object_id
         skip_service_principal_aad_check = true
       }
   ```

   **Output:**

   [image]

   [image]

   [image]

---

2. If you want to use Service Principal only instead of Identity , then you have to use **Service Principal Object Id** in the role assignment
   as the aks is also using the same Service Principal.The Code with
   Service Principal Block will be like below :

   ```
   provider"azurerm"{
       features{}
   }
   provider"azuread"{}
   # Service Principal Which is being used by AKS.
   data "azuread_service_principal" "akssp"{
       display_name = "aksspansuman"
   }
   data "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
         name     = "ansumantest"
   }

       resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "aks" {
         name                = "ansumantestaks"
         location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
         resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
         dns_prefix          = "ansumantestaks-dns"

         default_node_pool {
           name                = "system"
           node_count          = 1
           vm_size             = "Standard_B2ms"
           type                = "VirtualMachineScaleSets"
           availability_zones  = [1, 2, 3]
           enable_auto_scaling = false
         }

         service_principal {
         client_id = data.azuread_service_principal.akssp.application_id
         client_secret = "e997Q~xxxxxxxx"
         }

       }
       data "azurerm_container_registry" "acr_name" {
         name = "ansumantestacr"
         resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
       }
       resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "aks_to_acr_role" {
         scope                = data.azurerm_container_registry.acr_name.id
         role_definition_name = "AcrPull"
         principal_id         = data.azuread_service_principal.akssp.object_id
         skip_service_principal_aad_check = true
       }
   ```

   **Outputs:**

   [image]

   [image]

Comment: @AsumanBal-MT thank you for a very detailed answer with examples. I decided to use managed identity in the end and it worked perfectly fine. Thanks for your help, this great answer will help other people also!

Comment: Glad to be of help :) @BrianRyan!!

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for something, to assign a network contributor's role to AKS. The role assignment needs the principle ID. and I get that by inspecting AKS terraform object.

```
terraform state show azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks

---
    identity {
        principal_id = "9966f59f-745a-4210-abcd-123456789"
        tenant_id    = "18518570-0488-436a-abcd-123456789"
        type         = "SystemAssigned"
    }
```

so I realize then I just need to change `azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks.kubelet_identity[0].object_id` this part.

[image]

this resolved the issue for me

```
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "example" {

  scope                = data.azurerm_resource_group.staging-rg.id
  role_definition_name = "Network Contributor"
  principal_id         = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks.identity[0].principal_id
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation to dig into this, that helped to resolve another issue!