# Azure cannot get UUID from role in terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, uuid, roles

I am getting a role definition in terraform from azure with the following command:

```
data "azurerm_role_definition" "test_role" {
  name = "Test Role"
  scope = data.azurerm_subscription.test-subscription.id
}
```

With the id of the role I am trying to create a role assignment with terraform:

```
resource "azuread_app_role_assignment" "test_assignment" {
  app_role_id         = data.azurerm_role_definition.test_role.id
  ...
}
```

But when I run terraform plan I am getting the error:

> Error: Value must be a valid UUID

I also tried:

```
resource "azuread_app_role_assignment" "test_assignment" {
  app_role_id         = data.azurerm_role_definition.test_role.role_definition_id
  ...
}
```

This gave me the same error message.

Do you have any idea how to get the UUID of a role in terraform?

Comment: Aren't you mixing Azure AD application roles and Azure RBAC roles?!

Comment: RBAC role assignement is this one https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/role_assignment

Comment: @silent thanks for the hint. When I do it with azurerm_role_assignment its working. You are right, I mixed up azuread and azurerm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments:

You mixed up the different role assignments. What you are looking for is the RBAC assignment [azurerm_role_assignment](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/role_assignment)

Answer (score 2):

I tried below code and receieved same error:

```
resource "azuread_app_role_assignment" "aks_test_assignment" {
  app_role_id         =azurerm_role_definition.aks_cluster_admin_role.id
  principal_object_id = azuread_group.aks_admins_group.id
  resource_object_id  = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.example.id
}
```

Error:

```
Value must be a valid UUID
│
│   with azuread_app_role_assignment.aks_test_assignment,
│   on main.tf line 225, in resource "azuread_app_role_assignment" "aks_test_assignment":
│  225:   resource_object_id  = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.example.id
```

[image]

Here resource_object_id must be service principal object Id  .
Service principal can be obtained from creating application in azure ad.

Or

When the system assigned identity is used, the id of the system managed identity must be used.

***Azure ad role is different from azurerm role:***

[image]

Try below code:

```
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "example" {
  scope              = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.example.id
  role_definition_id = azurerm_role_definition.aks_cluster_admin_role.role_definition_id
  principal_id=     azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.example.kubelet_identity[0].object_id
}
```

or

```
resource "azurerm_role_definition" "aks_cluster_admin_role" {
  name        = "Network Contributor" #"AKSClusterAdminRole"
  description = "Allows management network of an AKS cluster"
  scope       = "/subscriptions/f10xxxxa71c"
  permissions {
    actions     = [
      "Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/*",
      "Microsoft.ContainerService/locations/*"
    ]
    not_actions = []
  }
  assignable_scopes = [
    azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.example.id
  ]
}

data "azuread_service_principal" "aks-aci_identity" {
  display_name = "sp${azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.example.name}"
  depends_on   = [azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.example]
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "aks-aci-vnet-assignment" {
  scope                = azurerm_virtual_network.example.id
  role_definition_name = "Reader"
  principal_id         = data.azuread_service_principal.aks-aci_identity.id
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "aks-aci-subnet-assignment" {
  scope                = azurerm_subnet.example-aci.id
  role_definition_name = "Network Contributor"
  principal_id         = data.azuread_service_principal.aks-aci_identity.id

}


  resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "example" {
  scope              =  "/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/example-aks1"
  principal_id=     azuread_service_principal.aks-aci_identity.id
  role_definition_name = "Contributor"
}
```

[image]

[image]

Also below code worked:

```
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "example" {
  scope              =  "/subscriptions/xxxc/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/example-aks1" #azurerm_container_registry.acr.id
  role_definition_name = "Contributor"
  principal_id  = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.example.kubelet_identity[0].object_id
 
}
```

[image]

Reference :

1. [Aks issues | Github](https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/1894)
2. [Azure role assignment Acr /aks | StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69916317/azure-role-assignment-aks-to-acr-terraform)